# Support for Foreground and Background geoprocessing in ArcMap tools?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing, arctoolbox

If not all ArcGIS tools support both foreground and background Geoprocessing, then how can I tell whether a tool will run in the foreground or run in the background?

Comment: Your question is too broad because it contains three questions when the [Tour] stipulates that there should be only one question per question.

Comment: but all these questions are related. So should be asked in one question.

Comment: You shold assume that all GP tools will run in the background  unless the "run in background" Geoprocessing option is disabled. This question *is* far too broad, since there are hundreds of tools, and dabbles in *opinion-based* as well, since "why was it coded this way" questions aren't likely to attract definitive answers.

Answer (score 3):

The tools that do ***not*** run in the background are listed on the help page entitled [Background Geoprocessing (64-bit)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm):

> Tools that do not run in the background include the following:
>
> - Tools inside the Metadata conversion toolset
> - Tools inside the Geodatabase administration toolset
> - All Coverage tools
> - Tools which create packages
> - Graphing tools (64-bit geoprocessing only; these tools work in traditional 32-bit background processing)
> - Custom script, model, or function tools where the author has disabled background processing
>
> ...
>
> Any script or script tools you run while inside Desktop honors the
>   background processing setting.

I encourage you to visit the help page for more information.